# How to transfer Likes number on the second page of WP article when using pagnation?

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like, permalinks, facebook-social-plugins

I have a really popular WP blog but I want to increase number of "pageviews" by splitting my articles on two article pages by using  code.

Everything works fine except the like button. On the second page of the article it's showing  zero Likes and when you like the article on the second page it share the URL of the second page.

Permalink structure looks like this: http://www.tarzanija.com/article-title/ and second page of the article is http://www.tarzanija.com/article-title/2/

Is there any way I can set my Like button to show count and URL of the first article page on the /2/ page?

Since this is my first post here I hope I didn't do anything wrong :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the `og:url` meta tag for both pages to be the same (`http://www.tarzanija.com/article-title/`).

Answer (score 0):

For no matter which page of the article you're on, always use http://www.tarzanija.com/article-title/ in the like plugin's code. Don't insert the page number or it will be counted as separate likes by Facebook.